# My code compile, execute but program crashes at the end

Tags: c++, string, vector, split, substring

```
// program that split a string and stock words in a vector array

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "substring using vector test\n" << endl;

bool reste(1);
vector<string> mots;   // our vector 'word' mots is french vector
size_t found(-1);      // init at - 1 because i need to wirte +1 to start at 0 
int prevFound(-1);     // same explanation, prevFound meaning previous found
string chaine ("let's test this piece of code");  

do
{
 found = chaine.find(" ",found+1);  // looking for the first space encountered


if (found!=string::npos)   // if a space is found..
{
   cout << "\nSpace found at: " << found << '\n';  // position of the first space
   mots.push_back(chaine.substr(prevFound+1,found-prevFound)); // add a 'case' in vector and substract the word //
   prevFound = found;  // stock the actual pos in the previous for the next loop


}
if (found==string::npos)    // if no space is remaining, extract last word
{
   cout << "\nlast word\n\n" << endl;
   mots.push_back(chaine.substr(prevFound+1,found-prevFound));
   reste = 0;
}

}while (reste);   


cout << "\nraw sentence : " << chaine << endl;

unsigned int taille = mots.size();  // taille meaning size
cout << "number of words" << taille << "\n" << endl;

for (int i(0); i<=taille; i++)  // loop showing the extracted words
{
cout << mots[i] << '\n';
}
return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your time.
I tried to translate most of my code coded in my mother tongue, i might be irrelevent on my expalanations.
I've been learning c++ online for two weeks now, be clement.

I just want to know why my code compile and execute but crashes at the end, my code do fine with static arry.
Maybe i need a set container ?
If yes, can someone correct my code with std::set.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your final loop is looping over one too many indices, so you access `mots` out of bounds.

Comment: since "npos is a static member constant value with the greatest possible value for an element of type size_t" in the case of if (found==string::npos) found-prevFound results in a way to big nr for the substr's length parameter

Answer (score 3):

Your program has undefined behavior because you access your vector **out of bounds**.

Change this :

```
for (int i(0); i<=taille; i++)
```

To :

```
for (int i(0); i<taille; i++)
```

Or more simply :

```
for (auto& mot : mots)  
{
    cout << mot << '\n';
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. can you explain me the for (auto& mot : mots)

Comment: it is a `for range` loop  : see[here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)